# Event for Red Close button of NSWindowController

Tags: cocoa, event-handling, nswindowcontroller

How can I handle an event where I click on the red close button of a NSWindowController?

Reason for asking is that I have a video playing in a new NSWindowController window and when user clicks on the red close button, the audio continues playing, so I want to use the event to close the video.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Make your `NSWindowController` subclass conform to the `NSWindowDelegate` protocol and be the delegate of the corresponding window. Having done that, implement:

```
- (void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // whichever operations are needed when the
    // window is about to be closed
}
```

in your `NSWindowController` subclass.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I need to observe the event, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44721893/1418457

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(windowWillClose(_:)), name: Notification.Name.NSWindowWillClose, object: nil)
```